# Looking for an RxJS operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am using an Angular service to allow the user to upload files.

The implementation of the service is working ; my question is about RxJS and its pipeable operators, but here is the service signature just in case :

```
askUserForFile(): Observable<File>;
toBase64(file: File): Observable<string>;
isFileValid(file: File, configuration?: { size?: number, extensions?: string | string[] }): boolean;
```

The call to this service is as follows :

```
  this.fileService
    .askUserForFile()
    .pipe(
      // this is the operator I'm looking for 
      unknownOperator(file => this.fileService.isFileValid(file, { extensions: ['txt'] }))
      mergeMap(file => {
        fichier.filename = file.name;
        return this.fileService.toBase64(file);
      }))
    .subscribe(base64 => {
      fichier.base64 = base64;
      // Rest of my code
    }, error => {/* error handling */});
```

I would like to find an operator in place of `unknownOperator` that would throw an error if the condition isn't met.

I've tried with

- `filter` : if the condition isn't met, the code stops after it,
- `map` : the code continues even if an error is thrown with `throwError`

I thought about using the following piping

```
.pipe(
  map(...),
  catchError(...),
  mergeMap(...)
)
```

Which I think might work, but I would like to find (if possible) an operator that shortens this piping.

Is it possible ? if not, is there a better piping ?

Comment: I'd just call `isValidFile` within the `mergeMap` and, if it returns a false value, either return a `throwError` observable or just  `throw` an error.

Comment: @cartant it works too, thank you, but I would have liked to be able to use an operator for that, I think this would have been cleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use just `map` but you have to throw an exception with `throw` keyword, not returning `throwError` because this just creates another Observable. You could also use `mergeMap` and then `throwError` would work but it's probably unnecessarily complicated.

```
map(val => {
  if (val === 42) {
    throw new Error(`It's broken`);
  }
  return val;
})
```

oneliner:

```
mergeMap(val => val === 42 ? throwError(new Error(`It's broken`)) : of(val))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but it removes the one-line condition ; is this the only way of doing it ?

Comment: Then it's probably easier to use `mergeMap`, see my update

Comment: It works too, but renders nasty because of the linter : `mergeMap(file => (this.fileService.isFileValid(file, { extensions: ['txt'] }) ? of(file) : throwError('Error ...')) as Observable<File>)` ... So there's really no built-in operator for that except for workarounds like that ?

Comment: well, you can put this into a custom operator.

Comment: I've never went that far into RxJS, I didn't know you could do that ! Thank you for the heads-up, I think I'm going to do that